# Script to copy SQL server table structures (filter + add columns)

Tags: sql, sql-server

is there a way I can write a script to find all tables with a given filter (e.g. all tables that start with "tbl_") and copy them (structure only) but adding a new standard column to each one?

I'm using SQL server 2008.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

Use the Metadata: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

Generate table creation scripts in a different schema or database or table name with the additional columns

Comment: Thank you - that was enough to help me find a more detailed answer here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/c7f4e2ee-f871-4ebf-868c-2c1f8a8fd2dd